# Sympy lambdify outputs weird behaviour when evaluated over numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sympy

I need to write some piece of code that works for general surfaces: I am given the parametric version of the surface S(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) and a curve on the surface, given by u = u(t), v = v(t). I want to obtain the value of S(u(t), v(t)) and, because I want my computation to be fast, I lambdify the expression. Let me give you a simple working example:

```
import sympy as sym

u,v,t = sym.symbols('u v t', real = True)
x,y,z = u,v,u*v/18 + sym.cos(u*v)/9 - sym.sin(u*v)/9
surface = sym.Matrix([x,y,z])
u_of_t, v_of_t = -2*(1-t) + 2*t, 0
surface_of_t = surface.subs([(u,u_of_t),(v,v_of_t)])
fsurface = sym.lambdify([t], surface_of_t)

fsurface(0)
# output array([[-2.], [ 0.], [ 0.11111111]])
```

Now, the fact that it returns an array of lists is not my ideal behaviour, but I can work around that. The problem arises when trying to evaluate fsurface ove a numpy array because I want to obtain the values over all those values of t, e.g.,

```
fsurf(np.array([0,0.5]))
#output array([[array([-2.,  0.])],[0],[0.1111111111111111]], dtype=object)
```

Because the value of v_of_t is set to 0, I expect the constant behaviour on both y and z, but that last output I'd like it to be returned as

```
fsurf(np.array([0,0.5])
# output array([[array([-2.,  0.])],  [0,       0],  [0.1111111111111111,        0.1111111111111111]]
```

Observe that this happens when repetition of values occurs within a row: setting

```
u,v,t = sym.symbols('u v t', real = True)
x,y,z = u,v,u*v/18 + sym.cos(u*v)/9 - sym.sin(u*v)/9
surf = sym.Matrix([x,y,z])
u_of_t, v_of_t = -2*(1-t) + 2*t, -2*(1-t) + 2*t
surf_of_t = surf.subs([(u,u_of_t),(v,v_of_t)])
fsurf = sym.lambdify([t], surf_of_t)
fsurf(np.array([0,0.5]))
# output array([[[-2.        ,  0.        ]],
#       [[-2.        ,  0.        ]],
#      [[ 0.23368432,  0.11111111]]])
```

produces the desired output.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you show `surface_of_t`, and the python code displayed by `help(fsurf)`.  You are getting object dtype arrays because it's trying to create an array from lists or arrays that differ in shape.  `sympy` doesn't `broadcast` in the same way that `numpy` does, so making an array from a sympy matrix can be tricky.

Answer (score -1):

```
In [5]: surface_of_t
Out[5]: 
⎡4⋅t - 2⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢   0   ⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣  1/9  ⎦
```

And the help of `fsurface` shows:

```
def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return array([[4*t - 2], [0], [1/9]])
```

Called with a scalar, the result is a (n,1) array:

```
In [8]: fsurface(0)
Out[8]: 
array([[-2.        ],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.11111111]])
```

With an array input:

```
In [11]: fsurface(np.array([0,1]))
<lambdifygenerated-1>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return array([[4*t - 2], [0], [1/9]])
Out[11]: 
array([[array([-2,  2])],
       [0],
       [0.1111111111111111]], dtype=object)
```

Did you get the warning?  See the code, the same return as the help?  This is sort information is important; don't ignore it.  TELL US ABOUT WHEN ASKING THE QUESITON.

`sparse.matrices` don't lambdify well.  `lambdify` does not "know" enough `numpy` to expand the `[0]` and `[1/9]` to arrays the same size as `t`.

Your second case has a `t` based expression in each cell:

```
In [14]: surf_of_t
Out[14]: 
⎡                   4⋅t - 2                    ⎤
⎢                                              ⎥
⎢                   4⋅t - 2                    ⎥
⎢                                              ⎥
⎢         2      ⎛         2⎞      ⎛         2⎞⎥
⎢(4⋅t - 2)    sin⎝(4⋅t - 2) ⎠   cos⎝(4⋅t - 2) ⎠⎥
⎢────────── - ─────────────── + ───────────────⎥
⎣    18              9                 9       ⎦

def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return array([[4*t - 2], [4*t - 2], [(1/18)*(4*t - 2)**2 - 1/9*sin((4*t - 2)**2) + (1/9)*cos((4*t - 2)**2)]])

In [16]: fsurf(np.array([0,1]))
Out[16]: 
array([[[-2.        ,  2.        ]],

       [[-2.        ,  2.        ]],

       [[ 0.23368432,  0.23368432]]])
```

With shape (3,1,2).

So you have found the fix - hopefully looking at these details explains why.

### Let's try lambdifying `surface`

, an expression with 2 variables (i.e. before the subs)

```
In [19]: surface
Out[19]: 
⎡            u            ⎤
⎢                         ⎥
⎢            v            ⎥
⎢                         ⎥
⎢u⋅v   sin(u⋅v)   cos(u⋅v)⎥
⎢─── - ──────── + ────────⎥
⎣ 18      9          9    ⎦

In [20]: foo = sym.lambdify([u,v],surface)

In [21]: help(foo)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(u, v)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(u, v)
    
    Expression:
    
    Matrix([[u], [v], [u*v/18 - sin(u*v)/9 + cos(u*v)/9]])
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(u, v):
        return array([[u], [v], [(1/18)*u*v - 1/9*sin(u*v) + (1/9)*cos(u*v)]])
    
    
    Imported modules:
```

and lambdify the `t` to `u` calculation:

```
In [22]: ufun = sym.lambdify([t],-2*(1-t) + 2*t)    
In [23]: help(ufun)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(t)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(t)
    
    Expression:
    
    4*t - 2
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(t):
        return 4*t - 2
    ...
In [24]: ufun(np.array([0,1]))
Out[24]: array([-2,  2])
```

Now try the `u` and `v`:

```
In [25]: foo(ufun(np.array([0,1])),0)
<lambdifygenerated-3>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return array([[u], [v], [(1/18)*u*v - 1/9*sin(u*v) + (1/9)*cos(u*v)]])
Out[25]: 
array([[array([-2,  2])],
       [0],
       [array([0.11111111, 0.11111111])]], dtype=object)
```

Oops, `v` needs to be an array that matches `u` in shape.  That's because of the element with just `[v]`.

```
In [26]: foo(ufun(np.array([0,1])),np.array([0,0]))
Out[26]: 
array([[[-2.        ,  2.        ]],

       [[ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.11111111,  0.11111111]]])
```

The result is (3,1,2) shape, where the (3,1) comes from the shape of `surface`, and (2,) from the `u`,`v` arguments.

### Using `sym.Array` instead

```
In [31]: surface = sym.Array([x,y,z])
In [32]: surface
Out[32]: 
⎡      u⋅v   sin(u⋅v)   cos(u⋅v)⎤
⎢u  v  ─── - ──────── + ────────⎥
⎣       18      9          9    ⎦
```

the lambdified code is

```
return numpy.array((u, v, (1/18)*u*v - 1/9*sin(u*v) + (1/9)*cos(u*v)))
```

and the result (3,2)

```
In [36]: foo(ufun(np.array([0,1])),np.array([0,0]))
Out[36]: 
array([[-2.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.11111111,  0.11111111]])
```

### list(surface)

If we lambdify a list instead of the matrix:

```
f = sym.lambdify([t],list(surface_of_t))
```

the python code returns a list rather than ragged array (with warning)

```
def _lambdifygenerated(t):
    return [4*t - 2, 0, 1/9]

In [19]: f(np.arange(4))
Out[19]: [array([-2,  2,  6, 10]), 0, 0.1111111111111111]
```

It may then be easier to 'clean' it up and make 2d array.

But it may be simplest to just evaluate the function at scalar values.

```
In [22]: [f(i) for i in np.arange(4)]
Out[22]: 
[(-2, 0, 0.1111111111111111),
 (2, 0, 0.1111111111111111),
 (6, 0, 0.1111111111111111),
 (10, 0, 0.1111111111111111)]

In [23]: np.array(_)
Out[23]: 
array([[-2.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111],
       [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111],
       [ 6.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111],
       [10.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111]])
```

Sure we try to avoid iterations with numpy, but sometimes they are the simplest.  And since you are using `sympy` you really aren't concerned with performance.

Here's a way of making a 2d array from the 'ragged' list:

```
In [24]: res = np.zeros((4,3))
In [25]: lst = f(np.arange(4))
In [26]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     res[:,i] = lst[i]
    ...:     
In [27]: res
Out[27]: 
array([[-2.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111],
       [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111],
       [ 6.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111],
       [10.        ,  0.        ,  0.11111111]])
```

Comment: If there is something missing from the question, please use the comment section to point it out, and vote to close the question. Definitely do not attempt to write an answer and then berate OP in the answer for missing information. Similarly if OP has put the expected effort into debugging code and identifying a specific problem in a specific place, consider VTC as "needs debugging details" or "needs more focus". Above all else, please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**, and that Q&A standards are quite different now vs. what they were in 2011.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I already asked for that information.  I put time into writing a full answer because I too was curious about why it didn't work.  I had an idea from past answers, but needed to clarify it.  Hopefully the OP will learn, and may even some mythical future viewer will find it helpful.  I'm active on SO because I like to learn and I like to teach.  I'm not here to meet some Q&A standards.  I might also add that good answers for `sympy` can differ from ones for plain `python`, or even `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you very much for dedicating time to give an elaborate answer. However, your  solution does not really apply to my case, because you needed to give both u and v as input when the whole idea about using u_of_t is being able to just give as input the parameter t: the real case scenario in which I am working involves arbitrary many curves on the surface and the surface is actually created as an object in which the curves are atributes.

Comment: My primary point was that you need to be aware of the limitations of using `lambdify`, especially when working with `sym.Matrix`, as well as the tools for identifying those problems.  You need to understand `numpy` better than `lambdify` does.  I can't provide a generic fix.

Comment: Since the original `fsurface` works with scalar arguments, you could just use a list comprehension to iterate over multiple values.  Converting the object array in Out[11] to a (n,m) array is possible, but not trivial

Comment: I added some code that explores alternate ways of building a 2d array of results.